# TFS connection string with user name/password

Tags: tfs

Is the scenario where TFS app server connection to the DB using user name/password (instead of integrated security), a supported one? If not, can it be done tinkering with web.configs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is documentation for earlier versions where you can find a connection string: [Services Web.Config File Settings in Team Foundation Server Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms400727(v=vs.80)).

I also have tried the change of a db account for my tfs 2015 and this works:

1. Find the web.config file under (TFS_Install_DIR)\Application Tier\Web Services:

[image]

2. Change the applicationDatabase key:

[image]

But this is unofficial way and I do not know any risks ))

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I was expecting to do something like this :)